# Loading cover pic Facebook SDK

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

im using the following:

```
$fql = "SELECT 
            name, pic, pic_cover, start_time, end_time, location, description 
        FROM 
            event 
        WHERE 
            eid IN ( SELECT eid FROM event_member WHERE uid = 127795963908033 ) 
        AND 
            start_time >= now()
        ORDER BY 
            start_time desc";

$param  =   array(
    'method'    => 'fql.query',
    'query'     => $fql,
    'callback'  => ''
);
```

and

```
       echo "<img src={$values['pic_cover']} width='600px' />";
```

This works great for pic, but when i change it to pic_cover as above it returns null.

any ideas? thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because its simply not the right name plus the actual field named 'cover' is an array.

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#100) Unknown fields: pic_cover.", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 100
  }
}
```

That should do:

```
echo $values['cover']['source']
```

You can always use the [OpenGraph Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) to see if your FQL executes correctly and what JSONs get returned.